# browser notification not appearing

Tags: javascript, notifications

I´m trying to show a notification with the following code:

```
if(Notification.permission === 'granted' && !this._active) {
    let n = new Notification(this._activeContact.name,{
        icon : this._activeContact.photo,
        body : data.content
});
```

But nothing appears!!
I already granted permission on request!!

by the way I have a function requesting the browser to grant permission

```
checkNotifications(){
    // debugger
    if (typeof Notification === 'function'){
        if (Notification.permission !== 'granted'){
            this.el.alertNotificationPermission.show()
        } else {
            this.el.alertNotificationPermission.hide()
        }

        this.el.alertNotificationPermission.on('click', e=> {
            Notification.requestPermission(permission => {
                if (permission === 'granted') {
                    this.el.alertNotificationPermission.hide()
                    console.info('notificações permitidas!')
                }
            })
        })
    }
}
```

and is not working on edge!!

Comment: Did you check for errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: @Barmar, no errors